# Can you use .slice while parsing to an int?

Tags: java

```
int ticket = Integer.parseInt(testTicket.slice(0, -1));
```

As seen in the code above, I'm trying to parse a string while also using slice to remove the last digit. While I could certainly add additional lines of code to get it done, I don't see any reason why the above shouldn't work.

When I try and use the above code, I get a compiler error:

```
  TicketNumber.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
      int ticket = Integer.parseInt(testTicket.slice(0, -1));
                                              ^
  symbol:   method slice(int,int)
  location: variable testTicket of type String
```

I don't know why it's not working and I think it's worth finding out so that I can make sure whatever is causing the error doesn't show up in my other programs.

Comment: Slice? Never used it... Substring maybe?

Comment: Are you sure there is a Slice() method? I have used substring & split?

Comment: I would appreciate if legitimate, if ignorant, questions weren't downvoted, as it prevents new users from asking questions, and delays new user's access to the features that allow them to contribute. Remember that most advice is not detailed enough to help new programmers, so unless you already know that, for example, slice() is a method for functions, not strings, you will never find out by googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get a compiler error... I don't see any reason why the above shouldn't work.

That's because `String#slice` [is not a method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) in the String class.

If you would like to remove the last character use the `substring` method.

```
testTicket.substring(0,testTicket.length() - 2);
```

Comment: That fixed it, is slice really not a method for strings? When I looked up how to get specific parts of a string, slice is the first thing that came up. Perhaps I accidentally searched for how to get parts of an integer?  

Having just googled .slice to try and find out, I have no idea how I came across it the first time around. It seems to be for arrays. How on earth did that come up when I was looking for strings.

Comment: Maybe you looked at javascript. There is a slice method there. You can look at the link I provided to see all the String methods

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea how I found my way to .slice based on what I searched for. Thanks for the explanation.